# Extract phone number and convert to whatsapp format

Tags: python, zapier

Im new to python, and I need to use it inside my Zapier automation.
In my automation, I want to convert phone numbers from various format to specific format (whatsapp url purpose).
How can I extract and convert below inputs to specific output using python?

input:
+62 812-3456-7890
62081234567890
6281234567890
+6281234567890
081234567890
(62)81234567890
(62)081234567890
(+62)81234567890
(+62)081234567890

output:
6281234567890

Additional information:
"62" is the country code for Indonesia
typically 8-12 digits including a "0" prefixing the "8nn"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the most optimal solution, but I wanted to keep it very simple, because you are a beginner in python.

```py
def decode(number: str):
    chars = ['+', '(', ')', '-', ' ']
    for c in chars:
        number = number.replace(c, '')

    return number
        
print(decode('+62 812-3456-7890'))
print(decode('(62)81234567890'))
```

`chars` is a `list` of characters that you want to remove from a number.

**EDIT**
I tried to test every number you gave in the question and I found out that code above doesn't work as you wanted. Here's my new solution and it passes all tests:

```py
def decode(number: str):
    chars = ['+', '(', ')', '-', ' ']
    for c in chars:
        number = number.replace(c, '')

    if number.startswith('0'):
        number = number[1:]
    if not number.startswith('62'):
        number = f'62{number}'
    if number[2] == '0':
        number = number.replace('0', '', 1)

    return number

tests = """+62 812-3456-7890
62081234567890
6281234567890
+6281234567890
081234567890
(62)81234567890
(62)081234567890
(+62)81234567890
(+62)081234567890"""
        
for num in tests.split('\n'):
    print(decode(num))
```

I added some `if` statments to handle all tests exeptions and also added test for each test case you gave.

The output of tests:

```
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about the problem is, instead of identifying the characters to toss, just keep the numbers:

```
def decode(number):
    out = []
    for c in number:
        if c.isnumeric():
            out.append(c)
    return ''.join(out)
```

Which can also be written as a list comprehension:

```
def decode(number):
    return ''.join( c for c in number if c.isnumeric() )
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the non-integer characters, here's a regex approach. `[^0-9]` specifies all characters that are not 0-9, and then replaces it with an empty string.

```py
import re
def decode(input):
    output = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', input)
    return output
```

List comprehension may be a little more intuitive. We essentially build an array that only contains numeric characters, and then return the joined array.

```py
def decode(input):
    output = [n for n in input if n.isnumeric()]
    return ''.join(output)
```

So if we want to pass the test cases, a little more work needs to be done (i.e. add the country code if there is none and remove the zero between the country code and the actual phone number).

```
def get_phonenum(input):
    # remove all non-numeric characters from the phone number
    only_digits = decode(input)

    # assuming that the inputs are constrained to country code 62
    only_digits = only_digits if only_digits[:2] == '62' else '62' + only_digits

    # remove zero between country code and actual phone number
    phone_num = only_digits[:2] + only_digits[3:] if only_digits[2] == '0' else only_digits

    return phone_num
```

Running

```
test = ['+62 812-3456-7890',
        '62081234567890',
        '6281234567890',
        '+6281234567890',
        '081234567890',
        '(62)81234567890',
        '(62)081234567890',
        '(+62)81234567890',
        '(+62)081234567890']

for t in test:
    print(get_phonenum(t))
```

Outputs

```
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
6281234567890
```

Comment: Keep it in mind that he gave test cases in the question and your solution does work always. For example in this case: `62081234567890`